# linux cp mtime change

Tags: linux, file, copy, cp

I have a piece of code monitoring a folder. If a file stay there for 3 minutes, my code will process it. It depends on the mtime to tell if it has been 3 minutes from now.

However, I find when I cp a huge file, let's say 10GB, that couldn't finish in 3 minutes, the code will break because **cp doesn't seem update mtime from time to time when it's copying**.

Did I observe the right behavior of cp?

Is there any work around?

Thanks,

Comment: Could you clarify what the cp command is used for? copy files into the process directory where they are then processed?

Comment: Assuming you don't have control of both sides. [Inotify at wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) [man inotify](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify).

Answer (score 3):

To the best that I know, the mtime gets updated when the aforementioned modification has been completed. And I think it is done so rightfully. Why would you need to know if a file is updated or not, while it is being copied on to ? If you happen to copy that file, you will end up with an incomplete file, probably will be useless.

But if your heart is definitely set on that, make sure your copy intelligence, depend not only the mtime but also the file size as suggested in the answer above. If you see a file size change in either way, regardless of what mtime says, you can be sure that the file has been modified, with respect to the last time it was processed.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of workarounds

- Copying into a dotfile and then moving it into place once the copy has completed - this would be done by the creating process, and only process non-dot files in the folder.
- Use a signal to indicate that the client has finished copying (probably only practical for non-network file systems)
- Use both the size of the file and the `mtime` and if neither increases in 3 minutes, then proceed with the processing.